# MySql - stores '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in place of default date value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table in mysql database with a datetime column. The default value of this column is set to '1900-01-01 00:00:00'.

However I have noticed that out of 4000 rows inserted, 1 row has this value set at '0000-00-00 00:00:00". I am very much confused about how this can happen despite of setting the default value.

Is this a known bug or issue in MySql? This happens approximately once in 4000 rows. Can anyone provide any help here?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: Invalid dates will be stored as ["Zero" value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html) in MySQL

Answer (score 6):

If your table looks like this:

```
create table foo (
  name VARCHAR(50),
  dob DATETIME DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
);
```

... it should [work just fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5694/1).

You should note that *default* value does not imply *mandatory*. You can still insert a different value or update the row to your liking:

```
insert into foo (name) values ('Jim'), ('Joe'), ('Jack');
insert into foo (name, dob) values ('Jill', '1999-12-31 23:59:59');
update foo set dob = current_timestamp where name='Jack';
```

That's what probably happened.

As of having a value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, it's known bug/feature that MySQL offers. Depending of your SQL mode, you're allowed to store invalid or incomplete dates.

**Edit:** To avoid the insertion of `0000-00-00` dates you need to harden the SQL mode:

```
mysql> SET sql_mode = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE foo SET dob='invalid' WHERE name='Jim';
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

mysql> SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE foo SET dob='invalid' WHERE name='Joe';
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: 'invalid' for column 'dob' at row 2
mysql>
mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+------+---------------------+
| name | dob                 |
+------+---------------------+
| Jim  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| Joe  | 1900-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Jack | 1900-01-01 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: well, providing value at the time of insert is always an option, but there is a reason we provide default value, it is to check if the row has an updated value or not.

Comment: @user1235483 I'm not sure of what your comment means. I've updated my answer, trying to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts.

`TIMESTAMP` has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC.

[**Official Doc**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Addition: Any other value would produce the "zero" value which would be "0000-00-00 00:00:00" for timestamp.

Comment: @Daniel Yes Correct...because they will be counted as invalid dates

Comment: Few rows do have default value set to '1900-01-01 00:00:00', so i doubt if I set any value out of the range it will set to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' instead

Comment: Dipesh, also let me clarify as mentioned in original post, this is a datetime type column not timestamp

Comment: The OP said `datetime`, not `timestamp`. I don't think there's nothing wrong with the [table design](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5694/1).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yes bro i did checked it on my server too,

Comment: Dipesh, like i said I can store 1900-01-01 too as a date value.

Comment: @user1235483 yes dude i did it on myside and its working, finding reason for the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql `DATETIME` field can't actually have a default value. Use `NOW()` on the query instead, or use `TIMESTAMP` data type which can be set default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: [Counter-example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58ce4/1). You're probably thinking of using *functions* as default value.

Comment: Dafeult value does work fine when no value is provided. So i doubt what you are saying is correct.