# How can I set the default value of a field as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

How can I set the default value of a field as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'? If we can't use '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as the default? What is the **basic** valid tiemdate?

For instance, this is the SQL for creating my article table,

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `article`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `article` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `article_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_from` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Set the article as new or featured from a datetime.',
  `date_to` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Set the article as new or featured to a datetime.',
  `backdated_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'The manual datetime that is modified or input by the user.',
  `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'The permanent datetime when the article is created.',
  `updated_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'The datetime when the article is updated on.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`, `parent_id`, `template_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `url_UNIQUE` (`url` ASC))
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 66
COMMENT = 'Entity that holds the article with one-to-one properties.';
```

I get this error when I run this query,

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'date_from'
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246881/mysql-stores-0000-00-00-000000-in-place-of-default-date-value

Comment: Why would you want to store an invalid date? If you want to mark the "absence of data" use `NULL`. Avoid "magic numbers"

Comment: Can't reproduce in MySQL 5.5. (Your version?) The primary key declaration won't work; the columns "parent_id" and "template_id" don't exist. But after fixing that, your CREATE TABLE statement works for me.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Cause of the error: the SQL mode**

You can set the default value of a `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` field to the special "zero" value of '0000-00-00' as dummy date if the sql mode permits it. For MySQL versions lower than 5.7.4 this is ruled by the NO_ZERO_DATE mode, see this excerpt of the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html):

> MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a 
>   “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL 
>   values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', 
>   enable the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode.

Additionally strict mode has to be enabled for disallowing "zero" values:

> If this mode and strict mode are enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted
>   and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well.

As of [MySQL 5.7.4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) this depends only on the strict mode:

> Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a 
>   valid date:
>
> If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts 
>   produce no warning.
>
> If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts 
>   produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE 
>   and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a 
>   warning.

**Check version and SQL mode**

So you should to check your MySQL version and the [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) of your MySQL server with

```
SELECT version();
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session
```

**Enable the INSERT**

You can set the sql_mode for your session with `SET sql_mode = '<desired mode>'`

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

**Valid range for DATETIME**

The supported range for `DATETIME` is

```
[1000-01-01 00:00:00] to ['9999-12-31 23:59:59'],
```

so the minimal valid DATETIME value is '1000-01-01 00:00:00'.
I wouldn't recommend to use this value though.

**Additional Note**

Since MySQL 5.6.5 all `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns can have the magic behavior (initializing and/or updating), not only `TIMESTAMP` and only one column at most, see [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically
>   initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
>   current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and
>   for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table. The following notes first
>   describe automatic initialization and updating for MySQL 5.6.5 and up,
>   then the differences for versions preceding 5.6.5.

You could change your CREATE TABLE statement in the case of MySQL 5.6.5 or newer to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `article_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_from` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Set the article as new or featured from a datetime.',
  `date_to` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Set the article as new or featured to a datetime.',
  `backdated_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'The manual datetime that is modified or input by the user.',
  `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'The permanent datetime when the article is created.',
  `updated_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'The datetime when the article is updated on.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`, `parent_id`, `template_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `url_UNIQUE` (`url` ASC))
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 66
COMMENT = 'Entity that holds the article with one-to-one properties.';
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a solution.
I'm not sure about the security of this so I recommend to

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode session
```

first. Save the value in your clipboard, then

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';
```

After that you can create or alter the table with default values like '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Answer (score 2):

Dates in SQL Server can only be between January 1, 1753 and December 31, 9999.

You have to decide how to handle default or missing datetimes as an organization or group (NULL, or one of these extremes). Typically our organization chooses to go with no date instead of the 1753 or the 9999 date. When there is no date, NULL is more appropriate than having any date at all, as ludicrous as something in the 1750's or 9999's may seem. Leaving missing dates as NULL will also avoid reports pulling bogus dates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: The OP did tag the question sql-server, but did so inappropriately, and the question isn't about Microsoft SQL Server at all.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the comment. Please delete my answer if you feel it does not apply to the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

because default valid datetime value after mysql version 5.6.5 as

1000-01-01 00:00:00 ~ 9999-12-31 23:59:59

so we can change mysql config to resolve the problem:

- show current mysql version and sql_mode:

```sql
select version() as version, @@sql_mode as sql_mode;
```

will output:
[image]

so, we need remove NO_ZERO_IN_DATE and NO_ZERO_DATE.

- modify mysql config file

```sh
vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

[mysqld]

...

sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

...

- save and restart mysql server

```sh
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

so easy!

Answer (score 1):

Replace code from :

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
      `article_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `date_from` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Set the article as new or featured from a datetime.',
      `date_to` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Set the article as new or featured to a datetime.',
      `backdated_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'The manual datetime that is modified or input by the user.',
      `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'The permanent datetime when the article is created.',
      `updated_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'The datetime when the article is updated on.',
      PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`, `parent_id`, `template_id`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `url_UNIQUE` (`url` ASC))
    ENGINE = MyISAM
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 66
    COMMENT = 'Entity that holds the article with one-to-one properties.';
```

to

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
      `article_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `date_from` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Set the article as new or featured from a datetime.',
      `date_to` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Set the article as new or featured to a datetime.',
      `backdated_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00' COMMENT 'The manual datetime that is modified or input by the user.',
      `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'The permanent datetime when the article is created.',
      `updated_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'The datetime when the article is updated on.',
      PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`, `parent_id`, `template_id`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `url_UNIQUE` (`url` ASC))
    ENGINE = MyISAM
```

Its working for me and it will helpful for php 7 and mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace the modes like this, it works.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',''));
```