# Error in MySQL database code while importing

Tags: mysql

my code :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `Id`         INT(10)   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `providerid` INT(10)   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `requestid`  INT(10)   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status`     BINARY(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `Id`          INT(255)                    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fromuid`     INT(255)                    NOT NULL,
  `touid`       INT(255)                    NOT NULL,
  `sentdt`      DATETIME                    NOT NULL,
  `read`        TINYINT(1)                  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `readdt`      DATETIME                             DEFAULT NULL,
  `messagetext` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `Id`                 INT(10) UNSIGNED    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username`           VARCHAR(45)         NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password`           VARCHAR(32)         NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email`              VARCHAR(45)         NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date`               DATETIME            NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `status`             TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `authenticationTime` DATETIME            NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `userKey`            VARCHAR(32)         NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IP`                 VARCHAR(45)         NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `port`               INT(10) UNSIGNED    NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);
```

> error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
>       `Id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,' at line 8

so plz help me correcting the code...

Thank you

Comment: only the primary key can be autoincrement

Comment: This could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349126/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-of-a-field-as-0000-00-00-000000

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your script.

1) there can be only one autoincrement key and it must be defined as a key

2) spelling mistable in third query of **DEFAULT** in

```
    `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

3) DEFAULT keyword used twice in 3rd query for below field and missing NULL for NOT NULL

```
`authenticationTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

CORRECT query:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
    `Id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `providerid` int(10) NOT NULL ,
    `requestid` int(10) NOT NULL ,
    `status` binary(1) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
    `Id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fromuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
    `touid` int(255) NOT NULL,
    `sentdt` datetime NOT NULL,
    `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `readdt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `messagetext` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ( 
    `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `authenticationTime` datetime NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `userKey` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `IP` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `port` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
```